# Density plot and Histogram discrepency

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

So I have two data frames, one is a strict subset of the other (it's the intersection between this data frame and another). the data frames are a list of variables and associated counts.

the problem I'm having is that the resulting density plots do not make sense for the data even when compared to the histograms graphing the exact same data

```
  ggplot()+
geom_histogram(data = vdjtoolTableTwo, aes(x = log10(frequency), y = after_stat(density), weight = count), fill=rgb(0,0,1,1/4)) +
geom_density(data = vdjtoolTableTwo, aes(x = log10(frequency), y = after_stat(density), weight = count), fill="black", alpha = 0.25)+
geom_histogram(data = tableOfGraphData, aes(x = log10(frequency.y), y = after_stat(density), weight = count.y), fill=rgb(1,0,0,1/4)) +
geom_density(data = tableOfGraphData, aes(x = log10(frequency.y), y = after_stat(density),  weight = count.y), fill = "red", alpha = 0.25)+
coord_cartesian(xlim = scale)
```

where tableOfGraphData is a strict subset of vdjTableTwo

the result is as follows

[image: histogram/density result]

you can clearly see in the histogram that the bluish table (vdjtoolTableTwo) is shifted slightly downward with a relatively higher concentration of low frequency values, and the redder histogram tableOfGraphData is shifted slightly towards higher values,

What confuses me is why the relative shape of the density plots doesn't correspond to the histogram. It feels like the red curve should be above the black curve at all points in the upper half but it isn't.

adding an "adjust = 1/5" to the density plot just further exasperates the issue

[image]

I'm sure this is something simple about how density plots work but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any suggestions on where to even start looking would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

To those who are having similar issues, the difference in data sets between the two density curves resulted in the kernels having a different standard deviation (as far as I can tell). Setting the bandwidth to a set value rather than a factor of the SD gives a consistent result across all the values

for my data it looks like this

```
 graphX <- ggplot()+
geom_density(data = onlyOne, aes(x = log10(frequency), weight = count), bw = 0.2, fill="black", alpha = 0.5)+
geom_density(data = tableOfGraphData, aes(x = log10(frequency.x), weight = count.x), bw = 0.2, fill = "red", alpha = 0.5)+
coord_cartesian(xlim = scale)+
theme_light()
```

giving this result

[image]